# (Unity) Shortest way to instantiate an object and obtain it script

Tags: unity, c#

Normally I use

```
ScriptName script = ((GameObject)Instantiate(
        Resources.Load("Prefab"),
        new Vector3(x, y, z),
        Quaternion.identity
    )).GetComponent<ScriptName>();
```

It is a little too long and too much of brackets, so I wondering if there is any other way to get instantiated object's script without break it in two statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I can, I try to hold a reference to the prefab(s) I might want to use, rather than use Resources.Load - that way they can be pre-fetched when I load the content that might use them, so I never have a hitch when spawning a new thing. It also helps me avoid accidental build bloat from having files in a Resources folder that I'm no longer using anywhere. With direct references, unused assets can be detected and stripped out at build time.

Here I'd have a member variable in the class that needs to do the spawning (or in a "dynamically spawnable objects catalog" that it can access) that's already typed as the kind of script I want out of it. That helps advertise intent in the Inspector, and prevents errors where I accidentally assign a prefab without the needed script.

```
public ComponentTypeIWant prefab;
```

Then when I want to spawn it, I write:

```
var spawn = Instantiate<ComponentTypeIWant>(
                 prefab,
                 new Vector3(x, y, z),
                 Quaternion.identity
            );
```

No GetComponent required - Instantiate returns the desired component directly (while still spawning the whole GameObject with all its scripts and child hierarchy intact).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do to make it shorter is to write a generic wrapper of some sort, with some overflow functions. This way you can just write:

```
    TestScript testScript = GenerateObject<TestScript>("cube", Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    TestScript testScript2 = GenerateObject<TestScript>("cube", Vector3.zero);
    TestScript testScript3 = GenerateObject<TestScript>("cube");
```

And the wrappers would look like:

```
public static T GenerateObject<T>(string name) where T : MonoBehaviour{
    return GenerateObject<T>(name,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
}

public static T GenerateObject<T>(string name, Vector3 position) where T : MonoBehaviour{
    return GenerateObject<T>(name,position,Quaternion.identity);
}

public static T GenerateObject<T>(string name, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)  where T : MonoBehaviour{

    // Verify object exists at load location
    UnityEngine.Object obj = Resources.Load(name);
    if (obj == null){
        Debug.LogError("Object does not exist within resources");
    }

    // Verify GamObject type when loading from Resources
    GameObject objToSpawn = obj as GameObject;
    if (objToSpawn == null){
        Debug.LogError("Loaded resource was not a GameObject");
    }

    GameObject gameObj = GameObject.Instantiate(objToSpawn,position,rotation);

    // Verify desired component is attached
    T component = gameObj.GetComponent<T>();
    if (component == null){
        Debug.LogError("LoadedResource did not have required component");
    }
    return component;

}
```

That being said, you should probably create a resource manager for your game that stores references to prefabs in some fashion so you aren't doing a ton of loading from Resources, or only load from resources once and reuses that reference whenever that asset is called for again. It is especially important for larger files, like textures.

Answer (score 1):

I...think that's about as succinct as you can get.

Nominally you can exclude the position and rotation parameters from [`Instantiate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) and you could use the Generic form of [`Resources.Load<>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), but it doesn't save you a whole lot:

```
ScriptName script = (Instantiate(
        Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefab")
    )).GetComponent<ScriptName>();
```

This, of course, assumes you don't care where your GameObject ends up and what rotation its facing, but it is, technically, shorter. `Quaternion.identity` is a default, so if you do need the position, but not rotation, you can omit that line entirely:

```
ScriptName script = (Instantiate(
        Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefab")
        new Vector3(x, y, z),
    )).GetComponent<ScriptName>();
```